# Subgroups of the group $GL_n(F_{17})$ of index 2 and 3

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I want to find subgroups of the group $GL_n(F_{17})$ of index $2$ and $3$ , where $F_{17}$ is a field with $17$ elements.

I thought about the group of matrices with determinant of 1. But is it of index 2? I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Since PSL is simple, these must be full inverse images of the multiplicative group of $F_{17}$ under the determinant.  Since the multiplicative group has order 16, there are no index 3 subgroups.  There is one index 2 subgroup...those invertible matrices who determinants satisfy $x^8=1$.

Note that SL has index 16 since all values in the field can be realized as determinants.  $GL/SL$ is cyclic of order 16, since $F_{17}^{\times}$ is cyclic of order 16.

For avoidance of doubt, this solution applies to all finite integers $n\ge 1$, except that the claims that PSL is simple applies only for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Could you explain how did you get to those conclusions? Since here we are talking about the group $GL_n(F_{17})$ and its order is much bigger than 16

Comment: Since PSL (SL mod its center) is simple, small index subgroups of GL must contain SL.

Answer (score 0):

The subgroup $SL_n(F_{17})$ of elements of $GL_n(F_{17})$ with determinant $1$ does not have index $2$---this is immediate for $n = 1$, for example.

On the other hand, we can modify your idea to produce a subgroup of order $2$: The map $$\det : GL_n(F_{17}) \to F_{17}^*$$
is a surjective group homomorphism, so for any subgroup $H \leq F_{17}^*$, $\det^{-1}(H)$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(F_{17})$ of index $[F_{17}^* : H]$. Thus, it's enough to find such an $H$ of index $2$. (NB your original idea is the special case $H = \{1\}$, and our observation shows that $[GL_n(F_{17}) : SL_n(F_{17})] = 16$.)

> The subset $H$ of squares in $F_{17}^*$ is a subgroup of order $2$. Checking shows that this is exactly the kernel of the map $F_{17}^* \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ defined by $x \mapsto x^8$. Assembling the pieces, $\ker (\det^8 : GL_n(F_{17}) \to \{\pm 1\})$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(F_{17})$ of order $2$.

Since $|F_{17}^*| = 16$, however, $F_{17}^*$ does not have a subgroup of index $3$ and hence we can't apply the above construction. Indeed, $GL_1(F_{17}) \cong F_{17}^*$, so for $n = 1$ there is no subgroup of index $3$. I don't know how to treat the problem for $n > 1$ (for which in particular $3 \mid |GL_n(F_{17})|$).